# `goBack` in react navigation doesn't go back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is my navigation.js:

```
export const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    'Specials': {
        screen:SpecialsScreen
    },
    'Menus': {
        screen:MenusScreen
    },
});

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    Explore: { screen: BottomTabs },
    'Support & Contact': { screen: ContactScreen },
    Settings: { screen: Settings, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    TOU: { screen: TOU, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Terms of Use'} },
    Privacy: { screen: Privacy, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Privacy Policy'} },
    Disclaimer: { screen: Disclaimer },
});
```

So the app launches and you get the`Home` screen:

```
App.js
render(){
    return(<Provider store={store}><Drawer /></Provider>)
}
```

From there you click 'I agree' to terms of use and get sent to `Explore` screen:

```
HomeScreen.js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Specials');
}}>
```

From `Specials` I hit the hamburger icon to toggle my drawer and go to `Support & Contact` from which there is a back button that I want to take me back to the previous screen:

```
ContactScreen.js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
}}>
```

But this takes me to `Home` and not `Explore` or `Specials` like I would imagine. What did I miss?

Comment: From Explore I hit the hamburger icon to toggle my drawer and go to this.props.navigation.goBack();

I do not understand your intention above

Comment: @SirKoswara I have reworded this.

Comment: Have you tried using `goBack(null)` instead?

Comment: @JoseVf Just tried, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add stack navigators

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ App: SpecialsScreen, MenusScreen });
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({ Home });
```